# what should i write for "no value" statement?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

im beginner in xcode.
How to code for something that you haven't yet to complete write information or no value in UILabel (labelDate) and then UIAlertView pop-up to tell you if you haven't yet input information?

My UILabel get input from code below

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    year = [picker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    month = [picker selectedRowInComponent:1];
    day = [picker selectedRowInComponent:2];
    date = @"";
    if(viewPicker.tag == 1)
        labelDate.text = [date stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d:%d:%d", year , month, day];
    else
    ... etc
}
```

and my button is like this

```
- (IBAction)readyBtn:(id)sender { 
    if ( ??? ) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please input date" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

I already tried out to write like this but i think it is not good idea because uialertview is popup if year,month,day is choosen to 0.

```
- (IBAction)readyBtn:(id)sender { 
    if (viewPicker.tag == 1) {
        year = month = day = 0;
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please input date" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

thank you for teaching me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Button event would be like this:

```
 - (IBAction)readyBtn:(id)sender 
 { 
    if ( labelDate.text.length >0 ) // Add OR condition for any other lablel or textField
    {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please input date" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you all for helping beginner like me!

Answer (score 0):

In your function if you wanna check if your UILabel has no value, do the following

```
- (IBAction)readyBtn:(id)sender { 
    if ( [yourLabel.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please input date" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the entered date whether it is nil or not , if it is nil then pop the alertview .
or

```
if(entereddate.text isEqualToString:" ")
{
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please input date" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];

}
```